# rendering a mask

Tags: rendering, masking

This most likely has already been asked, but here goes.

Im rendering some hair, generated from the scalp of a basic head geo. If i just render the hair with the head invisible, i can see through to the back face hair (that should be occluded by the head.)

I'd like to render the hair, with an alpha, ....where the head object would occlude the 'back faced' hair. The head geo would delete from the hair alpha where it is in front of it.

any help appreciated
M

[image]

**holdout shader was the answer for me**

Comment: Instead of adding a solution as part of the question, please write a proper answer that will help others that have a similar issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object material that is completely transparent, but occludes other objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223064/object-material-that-is-completely-transparent-but-occludes-other-objects)

Answer (score 0):

With Blender render add a white, shadeless material for the head and a black shadeless material for the hair, and turn the world white. If you render it you will get a two tone picture, what you can use as an alpha mask or easily convert to alpha in a picture editor.[image]

Comment: Thanks FF feller, it did work but think if found what i was after...

by adding a holdout shader to the face, it cuts away from the hair. perfect for my problem

thanks :)